# JdbcTemplate.update input from one table to other

Tags: java, batch-processing, jdbctemplate

I have a table "temp" and "data". I want to copy some specific data from "temp" table to "data" table along with some of my user data in batches.
Currently I have a code something like

```
JdbcTemplate.update("insert into Data(a, b, c, d, e) "
                + "select a, b, c, ?, e"
                + "from Temp where d= ?", id, Date);
```

But i want this to be done in batches as the data >10,00,000 rows and this fills us my transactional log with this single transaction, so need to break this single transaction into multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a `List` of all the parameters you want to insert and use a batch update using the following method.

```
public void insertBatch(final List<TempObj> TempList) {

   String str = "Your query here.";

   getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(str, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

        @Override
        public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i)
            throws SQLException {

            TempObj obj = TempList.get(i);
            ps.setString(1, obj.getId());
            ps.setDate(2, obj.getDate());

        }

        @Override
        public int getBatchSize() {
           return TempList.size();
        }

    });

}
```